# How to send an ICMP Port Unreachable package via C#?

Tags: c#, icmp

We're currently facing an issue with an unknown device in one of our customer's local networks. This device is sending an ICMP Port unreachable package to our client, which then leads to an unexpected behaviour.

In order to verify that a fix has covered this issue, i'd like to write a small application that runs on a random computer on the network, sending the same packages to our software. The only thing i've found so far is how to send ICMP Pings via C#, but this does not cover my needs.

Is there a way to achieve this using C#?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using nping. You can then just call nping from C# using the following nping command:

```
nping --icmp --icmp-type 3 --icmp-code 3 -c 1 myIp
```